# Android compare/search multiple images

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I got a list of images and an input image, I want to output true if the image exist in my list.
Images will consider to be equal if they got the same raw data.

Is there an easy way of doing this in Android?

I saw this method:

[`boolean Bitmap.sameAs(Bitmap)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)

But it require to test binary data against each of my images in the list and this is kind of expensive. Is there a better way doing this?

And what if I change the definition of equal images to "*similar"*, in such way that if the images got over 90% visual similarity they will consider to be equal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for the first part where equal images are those who got the same raw data.

You can hash each image and compare it by hash, this way you will test the image raw data only once.

```
String toSHA1(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    try {
        String sha1 = toSHA1(byteArray);
        stream.close();
        return sha1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

String toSHA1(byte[] data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(1, md.digest(data));
    return bigInteger.toString(Character.MAX_RADIX);
}
```